# Error in result part of Expectations : Jmockit/Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, jmockit

My test part is the following:

```
   @Test
        //testing user report method of UserAdmin - number of users less than 10 
        public void testuserReport_SizeLessThan10() throws Exception
        {
            new Expectations() {{
                dBConnection.getUsers();
                times=1;
                result= Arrays.asList("Abc","123");
            }};

            System.out.println("in less than 10");
            userAdmin.runUserReport();
        }
```

The method under test belonging to a class named userAdmin is the following:

```
public void runUserReport() {
        try {
            List<User> users = dbConn.getUsers();
            System.out.println(users.size());
            if (users.isEmpty()) { // empty database
                System.out.println("No users in database...");
            } else if (users.size() <= 10) { // detailed reporting
                System.out.println("Listing all usernames:");
                for (User user : users) {
                    System.out.println(user.getUsername());
                }
            } else { // summary reporting
                System.out.println("Total number of users: " + users.size());
                System.out.println(users.get(0).getUsername());
                System.out.println(users.get(1).getUsername());
                System.out.println(users.get(2).getUsername());
                System.out.println(users.get(3).getUsername());
                System.out.println(users.get(4).getUsername());
                System.out.println((users.size() - 5) + " more...");
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("DBConnection problem at runUserReport().");
        }
    }
```

My tests runs by giving the size of users as 2 but it does not print the usernames starting with "Listing all usernames:" as defined in the method. Am i defining the result wrongly in the expectations part of the test? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not even sure how come `System.out.println(users.size());` prints the size as 2 and not the test fails.

`List<User> users = dbConn.getUsers();` says that `users` is a List of User type while `result= Arrays.asList("Abc","123");` makes `result` as List of String, `List<String>`. You are assigning `List<String>` to `List<User>` and somehow it doesn't fail at run time.

You need to prepare a List of User type and assign to `result` instead of what you are doing currently.